# Inefficient Solution - Advent of Code 2021, Day 3, Part 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is working but it is extremely long. So, I guess there is a way to make it shorter/more efficient.

The problem solved here is from Advent of Code 2021, Day 3, Part 1: https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3

```
binary_list = open("data.txt").read().split("\n")

counter_1st_bit_0 = 0
counter_1st_bit_1 = 0

counter_2nd_bit_0 = 0
counter_2nd_bit_1 = 0

counter_3rd_bit_0 = 0
counter_3rd_bit_1 = 0

counter_4th_bit_0 = 0
counter_4th_bit_1 = 0

counter_5th_bit_0 = 0
counter_5th_bit_1 = 0

counter_6th_bit_0 = 0
counter_6th_bit_1 = 0

counter_7th_bit_0 = 0
counter_7th_bit_1 = 0

counter_8th_bit_0 = 0
counter_8th_bit_1 = 0

counter_9th_bit_0 = 0
counter_9th_bit_1 = 0

counter_10th_bit_0 = 0
counter_10th_bit_1 = 0

counter_11th_bit_0 = 0
counter_11th_bit_1 = 0

counter_12th_bit_0 = 0
counter_12th_bit_1 = 0


gamma_rate_queue = []
epsilon_rate_queue = []


for i in range(0, len(binary_list), 1):
  for j in range(0, len(binary_list[i]), 1):

    if binary_list[i][0] == "0":
      counter_1st_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][0] == "1":
      counter_1st_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][1] == "0":
      counter_2nd_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][1] == "1":
      counter_2nd_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][2] == "0":
      counter_3rd_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][2] == "1":
      counter_3rd_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][3] == "0":
      counter_4th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][3] == "1":
      counter_4th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][4] == "0":
      counter_5th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][4] == "1":
      counter_5th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][5] == "0":
      counter_6th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][5] == "1":
      counter_6th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][6] == "0":
      counter_7th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][6] == "1":
      counter_7th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][7] == "0":
      counter_8th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][7] == "1":
      counter_8th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][8] == "0":
      counter_9th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][8] == "1":
      counter_9th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][9] == "0":
      counter_10th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][9] == "1":
      counter_10th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][10] == "0":
      counter_11th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][10] == "1":
      counter_11th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][11] == "0":
      counter_12th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][11] == "1":
      counter_12th_bit_1 += 1


def gamma_rate_finder():

  if counter_1st_bit_0 > counter_1st_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_1st_bit_0 < counter_1st_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_2nd_bit_0 > counter_2nd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_2nd_bit_0 < counter_2nd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_3rd_bit_0 > counter_3rd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_3rd_bit_0 < counter_3rd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_4th_bit_0 > counter_4th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_4th_bit_0 < counter_4th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_5th_bit_0 > counter_5th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_5th_bit_0 < counter_5th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_6th_bit_0 > counter_6th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_6th_bit_0 < counter_6th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_7th_bit_0 > counter_7th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_7th_bit_0 < counter_7th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_8th_bit_0 > counter_8th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_8th_bit_0 < counter_8th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_9th_bit_0 > counter_9th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_9th_bit_0 < counter_9th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_10th_bit_0 > counter_10th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_10th_bit_0 < counter_10th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_11th_bit_0 > counter_11th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_11th_bit_0 < counter_11th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_12th_bit_0 > counter_12th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_12th_bit_0 < counter_12th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  gamma_rate = ''.join(gamma_rate_queue)

  return gamma_rate


def epsilon_rate_finder():

  if counter_1st_bit_0 < counter_1st_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_1st_bit_0 > counter_1st_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_2nd_bit_0 < counter_2nd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_2nd_bit_0 > counter_2nd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_3rd_bit_0 < counter_3rd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_3rd_bit_0 > counter_3rd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_4th_bit_0 < counter_4th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_4th_bit_0 > counter_4th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_5th_bit_0 < counter_5th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_5th_bit_0 > counter_5th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_6th_bit_0 < counter_6th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_6th_bit_0 > counter_6th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_7th_bit_0 < counter_7th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_7th_bit_0 > counter_7th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_8th_bit_0 < counter_8th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_8th_bit_0 > counter_8th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_9th_bit_0 < counter_9th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_9th_bit_0 > counter_9th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_10th_bit_0 < counter_10th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_10th_bit_0 > counter_10th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_11th_bit_0 < counter_11th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_11th_bit_0 > counter_11th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_12th_bit_0 < counter_12th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_12th_bit_0 > counter_12th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  epsilon_rate = ''.join(epsilon_rate_queue)

  return epsilon_rate


binary_gamma_rate = gamma_rate_finder()
binary_epsilon_rate = epsilon_rate_finder()


def Binary_to_DecimalValue(n):
  b_num = list(n)
  value = 0
  for i in range(len(b_num)):
      digit = b_num.pop()
      if digit == '1':
          value = value + pow(2, i)
  return value


gamma_rate = Binary_to_DecimalValue(binary_gamma_rate)
epsilon_rate = Binary_to_DecimalValue(binary_epsilon_rate)


PowerConsumption = gamma_rate * epsilon_rate

print("Gamma rate is: {} | {}".format(gamma_rate, binary_gamma_rate) + "\n" + "Epsilon rate is: {} | {}".format(epsilon_rate, binary_epsilon_rate) + "\n" + "The Power Consumption is: {}".format(PowerConsumption))
```

Any advice about my code would be helpful, I guess there is a way to replace lists here and to make the loops and functions more efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very hardcoded way to go about things. For starters, I see a lot of `if` that should've been `elif`. What version of Python did you write this for?

Comment: Why do you stop on _12th_ bit?

Comment: @vnp is appears that the sample given only has twelve lines of input.  But it's not guaranteed for the puzzle input that I can see.  @zаѓатhᵾѕтѓа Generally speaking, if you have variable names like `...5th...`, you need to step back and think if you should be using a list instead.  And `for i in range(len(somelist))` is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: @vnp For context, the input to this problem is randomized per user but the format of that input is constant: a list of 1,000 12-digit binary numbers. Which does justify hard-coding `12` here since the input will never contain a binary number that is not 12 digits long.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.2, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just going to make one suggestion, which you should be able to apply across a lot of your code.

1. Use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list) structures, which are analogous to *arrays* in other languages.

That's it. Lists.

### Use lists for counting values

Your first use should be to replace the 0/1 variables in counting code:

```
counter_1st_bit_0 = 0
counter_1st_bit_1 = 0
```

Let's make those two variables into a single list with two elements:

```
counter_1st_bit = [0, 0]
```

(***Note:*** the `[0, 0]` syntax is a list literal. These things are so common that Python supports typing them directly into the code.)

Now you can access `counter_1st_bit[0]` and `counter_1st_bit[1]` as two separate values (which they are!) and update them based on your input:

```
if binary_list[i][0] == "0":
  counter_1st_bit[0] += 1
elif binary_list[i][0] == "1":
  counter_1st_bit[1] += 1
```

Once you make that change, you can go one step farther and convert the string value to an integer value:

```
bit = int(binary_list[i][0])
if bit == 0:
    counter_1st_bit[0] += 1
elif bit == 1:
    counter_1st_bit[1] += 1
```

Then you realize that the bit value can *only* be either 0 or 1, so it's not `if` / `elif` but rather `if` / `else`:

```
bit = int(binary_list[i][0])
if bit == 0:
    counter_1st_bit[0] += 1
else:
    counter_1st_bit[1] += 1
```

And *then* you realize that the 0 and 1 are the values of `bit`:

```
bit = int(binary_list[i][0])
if bit == 0:
    counter_1st_bit[bit] += 1
else:
    counter_1st_bit[bit] += 1
```

And *then* you realize that the statements are the same, so you don't need the `if` and `else`:

```
bit = int(binary_list[i][0])
counter_1st_bit[bit] += 1
```

Now you're cooking with gas! Because you're only using the `bit` value one time, in one place, you can get rid of that variable:

```
counter_1st_bit[int(binary_list[i][0])] += 1
```

And you can make the same change across all the counter variables:

```
counter_1st_bit[int(binary_list[i][0])] += 1
counter_2nd_bit[int(binary_list[i][1])] += 1
counter_3rd_bit[int(binary_list[i][2])] += 1
counter_4th_bit[int(binary_list[i][3])] += 1
:
counter_12th_bit[int(binary_list[i][11])] += 1
```

And *then* you realize that your `counter_xxx_bit` variables could be replaced by a `list` of 12 lists!

```
# at start:
counter = [[0,0] for _ in range(12)]

# in loop:
for j in range(0, len(binary_list[i]), 1):
    counter[j][int(binary_list[i][j])] += 1
```

(***Note:*** The `[... for ... in ...]` syntax is called a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension). It's a shorthand that allows specifying the contents of a list as a single *expression.* This is super-valuable in places where statements are not permitted, like argument defaults and *lambda functions*. And initializing list variables...)

You can probably see how to make similar changes to your `gamma` and `epsilon` computation functions.

Comment: Good answer, especially for its tight focus on using collections (lists, in this case) rather than a proliferation of individual variables.

Comment: The `for` loop could be simplified further using `enumerate`, and I'm sure there's probably some way of doing the whole thing in one line without needing a separate initialization step.